# GOLANG: composite literal uses unkeyed fields

Tags: go

I've been given the following code:

```
package catalog
...
type Time time.Time
func (t Time) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
   got := time.Time(t)
   stamp := fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\"", got.In(time.UTC).Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"))
   return []byte(stamp), nil
}
```

and I'm trying to use it like:

```
package main

func main() {
   ...
   t := *a.StartTime  <<== This returns a time.Time
   t2 := catalog.Time{t}
}
```

And, I get the following error:

```
catalog.Time composite literal uses unkeyed fields
implicit assignment of unexported field 'wall' in catalog.Time literal
cannot use t (type time.Time) as type uint64 in field value
too few values in structure initializer
import (catalog ".../go-catalog-types.git")
```

I've also tried: t2 := catalog.Time{Time: t} and several other variations.  Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I think you are wanting to do

```
t2 := catalog.Time(t)
```

You have declared `catalog.Time` as a type with an [underlying type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) of `time.Time`, so to convert between them you need to do `catalog.Time(time.Time)`.

Currently you have written it as if you had an [embedded type](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding), which would only work if you had

```
type Time struct {
    time.Time
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/zbwf6ZfvX3